# Objective-C setNeedsUpdateConstraints vs. updateConstraintsIfNeeded

Tags: objective-c, constraints

I have read Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/) on these two methods, but I still don't quite understand.

What is the difference and why would I use either `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`?

Comment: What platform? OSX or iOS?

Comment: Sorry about that, iOS is what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` you are hinting the system that the constraints need to be recalculated at the next layout pass, nothing actually happens when you call this method, let's say you're just setting a flag.

When you call `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, you are instead actually asking the system to recalculate the constraints in that particular moment of execution, after this call the constraints will hold the newly updated values (although it does not necessarily mean that the UI has been updated already!). This is the method that the system automatically invokes at each layout pass, to trigger the recalculation for the constraints.